# get count of two table fields in one query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the count of females and males in the gender field of a table.

Is there a way to get the count of each in one query?

Something like:

```
select * from table count(where gender = 'm') as total_males, count(where gender = 'f') as total_females;
```

or will it require two queries?

```
select count(*) from table where gender = 'm';
select count(*) from table where gender = 'f';
```

Comment: How is this related to `sequel` (as opposed to `SQL`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basically a `PIVOT`. MySQL does not have a pivot so you can use an aggregate function with a `CASE` statement to perform this:

```
select
  sum(case when gender = 'm' then 1 else 0 end) Total_Male,
  sum(case when gender = 'f' then 1 else 0 end) Total_Female
from yourtable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/57b2d/1)

Or using `COUNT`:

```
select
  count(case when gender = 'm' then 1 else null end) Total_Male,
  count(case when gender = 'f' then 1 else null end) Total_Female
from yourtable;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/57b2d/3)

Comment: Thanks, sped up my query quite a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will work:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(t.gender='m',1,0)) AS total_males
     , SUM(IF(t.gender='f',1,0)) AS total_females
  FROM mytable t
```

The "trick" here is that we are using a conditional test to return either a 0 or a 1 for each row, and then adding up the 0's and 1's.  To make this a little more clear, I am using the `SUM` aggregate function rather than `COUNT`, although `COUNT` could be used just as easily, though we'd need to return a NULL in place of the zero.

```
SELECT COUNT(IF(t.gender='m',1,NULL)) AS total_males
     , COUNT(IF(t.gender='f',1,NULL)) AS total_females
  FROM mytable t
```

Consider that the two expressions in the SELECT list of this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) 
     , SUM(1)
  FROM mytable t
```

Will return the same value.

If you want to avoid the MySQL `IF` function, this can also be done using the ANSI SQL `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT SUM( CASE WHEN t.gender = 'm' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )) AS total_males
     , SUM( CASE WHEN t.gender = 'f' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )) AS total_females
  FROM mytable t
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select sum(case when gender='m' then 1 else null end) as total_males,  sum(case when gender='f' then 1 else null end) as total_females from ...
```

Should work just fine!

Answer (score 0):

If your only issue is to avoid two queries, you can always write two queries as subselects of one query.

Select (select 1 from dual) as one, (select 2 from dual) as  two from dual

This would work for your scenario, too.

Comment: If the reason to avoid multiple queries was performance, this won't help. Still a nice idea.

Comment: If you've got a really slow DB connection, this query would be faster ;-)